# Custom filter list keeps resetting when going back a page

Tags: bug

I have this custom filter; having a certain tag and sorted by "Newest".

When I click it in the right menu, it gives me a nice overview of new questions with this tag. Now, when clicking one of those questions and using the back function of my browser I expect to come back to this list. However, for some reason the list resets and displays questions which are displayed "asked 1 minute ago" (or whatever) but when opening that question it is actually a lot older, 5 hours in this case.

Clicking the custom filter's name in the right menu reloads the correct list again.

It feels like it is somehow falling back to some cached version of this list instead of the most recent one.

How can I prevent this behaviour and make sure I always come back to the latest version of this list?

Comment: It's known that browsers load cached versions of pages in the current session when going back. Just hit refresh.